# A problem occurred while attempting to migrate Magetno 1.9 differential data to Magento 2.2

Tags: magento2, magento2.2

I dumped the Magetno 1.9 database a few months ago.
The dumped database was rebuilt in the development environment and the data was migrated to Magento 2.2.

Below is the current problem.

The original Magento 1.9 database was deleted.
We then rebuilt the newly dumped database in the development environment and imported the differential data into Magento 2.2, but the data was not migrated.

What should I do in such a case?

Comment: create new migration , that`s all that you can do

Comment: Magento 1.9 table is missing m2 _ * table. Is there any problem?

Comment: did you create backup of 1.9 before migration ?

Comment: I didn't make a backup.

Comment: I mean dump ( backup )

Comment: There is no first dump.

Comment: create a new  for magento 2, take your m1.9 one and do migration again,  and check console for y errors, check logs and etc. Somewhere you will got an error